# SpriteFont error in monogame on macOS "Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException has been thrown The content file was not found."

Tags: c#, macos, xna, monogame, spritefont

I am trying to follow tutorials on monogame. using Xamarin studio 6.3 and Monogame content pipeline tool 3.6.

The error "Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException has been thrown The content file was not found." keeps appearing. I have looked online and followed some advice, such as moving the font file from ~/Library/Fonts/  to /Library/Fonts/ and tried re-installing the programs. I'm not having any luck though. Always get the same error message.

I found a few posts such as the ones here: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/5900

and here:
http://community.monogame.net/t/pipeline-fails-to-generate-spritefont/8204

but they say the issue is fixed?

I'm following this tutorial:
http://xnafan.net/2013/04/simple-platformer-game-in-xna-tutorial-part-five-improved-collision-detection/

Just to clarify, I know XNA and Monogame are different things and i've also been following a monogame tutorial here which also doesn't work.
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-drawing-text-with-spritefonts

Everything is working fine up to the "Adding debug info to the game" section. I've tried several different tutorials incase something was missing from this one but no luck.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you

Nick.

Comment: You aren't following a MonoGame tutorial; you are using an XNA tutorial. While they are similar, they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix to the issue! If you download the developer version 3.7 and rebuild from the pipeline tool it works! The link to the dev version is here. download the whole thing as the pipeline tool is included.
http://teamcity.monogame.net/repository/download/MonoGame_PackageMacAndLinux/latest.lastSuccessful/MonoGame.pkg?guest=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem a lot of people have that are new to MonoGame. The Content management system for MonoGame works completely different from XNA. The tutorial you're watching shows how to add content to an XNA game, not a MonoGame game. To add content to MonoGame, you need to open the file called Content.mgcb. This will bring you to a new window where you can add your content. Once you have added the content to Content.mgcb, you can save the file and use the Content. I will include step by step pictures to try and assist you in the process.

Step 1:
Find the Content.mgcb file and open it.
[image]

Step 2: Select the "Add Existing Item" button.
[image]

Step 3: Navigate to the file you wish to add. Select the item and click "Open".
[image]

I hope I was able to help.

Good luck,
- GHC

Comment: Thats exactly what i've been doing and it's not working. I did look up the differences and downloaded the pipeline tool (which opens when you click on the mgcb file) I've also been following this tutorial which is for monogame and got stuck at the same part.. http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-drawing-text-with-spritefonts